# InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table openeventstream"

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

I'm trying to run CQL from Cassandra in Python. But I got this error,

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table openeventstream"
```

Do anyone have an idea what's going on?

Code:

```
session = cluster.connect()
session.set_keyspace('meetup')
rows = session.execute('SELECT *  FROM meetup.openEventStream')
for x in rows:
    print x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra converts unquoted text to lowercase so you need to put your table name inside quotes:

```
rows = session.execute('SELECT *  FROM meetup."openEventStream"')
```